# java read url and select titleand list items

Tags: java

Code that reads url and selects list items tag and title t code should read what is the page title and the string between list item tag from ordered list

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class StringUtilitiesFromFile  {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       

            String url = "http://www.google.com";             

    String title = StringUtils.substringBetween(url, "<title>", "</title>");
    System.out.println("title:" + title); // good

    String[] tds = StringUtils.substringsBetween(url, "<li>", "</li>");
    for (String td : tds) {
        System.out.println(td);
    }               
}
}
```

Comment: i cant understand what you want??

Comment: how could read html page title and contents <li> which is list item programatically with java

Comment: Use a dedicated library to work with HTML like [jsoup](https://jsoup.org)

Comment: dont keep downgrading the question just because you dont understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string url is what the stringutils reads must find another way for actual url

thancs 4 lookn